# How to pass a string containing double quotes to a BAT file as an argument

Tags: c#, command-line, batch-file

My C# program needs to pass a string to a BAT file as the argument of the BAT file. This string may contain arbitrary characters such as double quotes, space and etc. I tried to escape all the characters by prefixing it by ^ but it does not work for the double quotes. I tried to escape the double quote by prefixing it with “\” but it adds a “\” to the argument when it is passed to the BAT file. For example: 
if mystring is “hello “there” &test”, the argument becomes “Hello \”there\” &test”.
How can I pass the string “hello “there” &test” as the argument? Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
@"hello ""there"" &test"
```

Comment: Can you explain what the `@` is used for?

Comment: @ is used for verbatim string literals. See [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I think the current answer should work. Let us know if it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, but it is used *outside* the literal. Which is why your previous version wouldn't have worked, or else it would have surprised me. Seems that an @ with double quotes for escaping is the way go, +1 for checking it up with the MSDN reference...

Comment: You're right. I've done somethng similar to the first example, but within StringBuilder not a single string. I blame too quick fingers.

Comment: How can I add this extra double quote programatically? I tried

Comment: I tried string quote=@"""; but this statement is not valid. I wrote a function to loop through every char in the string and chech whether it is a double quote, if it is, I need to prefix with the extra double quote but how can I add this quote in? also not all the quotes are in pairs in my string. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried the above solution. I can not make it working. Let me be more specific. If my stringA = "h "t & f" and stringB = "good"  I want stringA be the first argument , stringB be treated as the second argument. So the space, the " and & should not be interpreted as metacharacters by CMD.

Comment: What error you get using `string quote = @"hello ""there"" & test";` ?

Comment: I still did not get this to work at the end so I removed all the double quotes in the string and then handled the string for other sepcial characters, then passed the string out in double quotes. Thank for all your help.